# ARC(Automatic Reference Counting) in Action

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently following the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Here is my question:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        println("\(name) is being initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var reference1: Person?
        var reference2: Person?
        var reference3: Person?
        reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
        // prints "John Appleseed is being initialized
        reference2 = reference1
        reference3 = reference1

        reference1 = nil
        reference2 = nil
    }
}
```

After `reference1` equals `nil`, ARC deallocates the instance and prints `"John Appleseed is being deinitialized"`

Should not it be deallocates after `reference3 = nil`?

Comment: @JakubVano To get more information i am running this code in viewDidLoad() method. However reference3 is not nil, compiler deallocates instance even the Strong reference exists.

Comment: That screenshot added clutter, not clarity.

Comment: How are you determining the *exact* moment that the `deinit` occurs?  I would expect it to be called as soon as the method returns (and definitely not a moment later).  It may be called earlier due to some sort of optimization, but it's definitely not going to hang around after the method returns.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, there are 3 strong references to Person instance. I broke the 2 references by setting them nil. However there is still 1 strong reference. How compiler calls the deinit method?

Comment: Because the third is set to `nil` as soon as it falls out of scope, which is as soon as the `viewDidLoad` method returns.

Comment: I added some breakpoints and you are right, deinit occurs after viewDidLoad method returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is a matter of scope.  We can find out more with breakpoints.

Here, we are stopped just before we initialize `reference1`.
All variables are expectedly `nil`:

[image]

And after the initialization of `reference1`?

[image]

---

Okay, let's skip forward to after `reference2` and `reference3` are set:

[image]

All three variables point to the same memory location, and we can see the initializer only ran once.  These all point to the same location.

Let's step forward:

[image]

`reference1` is now pointing to `None`.  It is `nil`.  The `deinit` mmethod has not been called and printed its message.

Let's step forward some more:

[image]

Now `reference1` and `reference2` are both expectedly `nil`.  The `println` statements I've added were called.  But `deinit` did not run and `reference3` is not `nil`.

The next step is stepping all the way out of the method.  Once we're out of the method, the variables are out of scope and the `deinit` is called:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is deallocating because, compiler is able to recognise that there is no more use of locally created object. For example in below code after execution of `viewDidLoad` method `Person` will be deallocated because there is no one to use person object in future.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.\

        var reference1: Person?
        var reference2: Person?
        var reference3: Person?
        reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
        // prints "John Appleseed is being initialized
        reference2 = reference1
        reference3 = reference1

        reference1 = nil
        reference2 = nil

//        println(reference3?.name)
}
```

If you want to retain the object then you need to create `reference3` as `property` as below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var reference3 : Person?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var reference1: Person?
        var reference2: Person?

        reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
        // prints "John Appleseed is being initialized
        reference2 = reference1
        reference3 = reference1

        reference1 = nil
        reference2 = nil

//        println(reference3?.name)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        println(reference3?.name)
    }

}
```

Comment: I can access the **reference3?.name** even if **reference3** is not global.

Comment: No app will not compile if you are declaring reference3 in didLoad and using  in didAppear.